# Better to update a small vertex buffer, or send a uniform?

Tags: c++, opengl, user-interface, shader

I'm writing/planning a GUI renderer for my OpenGL (core profile) game engine, and I'm not completely sure how I should be representing the vertex data for my quads.  So far, I've thought of 2 possible solutions:

1) The straightforward way, every `GuiElement` keeps track of it's own vertex array object, containing 2d screen co-ordinates and texture co-ordinates, and is updated (`glBufferSubData()`) any time the `GuiElement` is moved or resized.

2) I globally store a single vertex array object, whose co-ordinates are `(0,0)(1,0)(0,1)(1,1)`, and upload a `rect` as a `vec4` uniform (x, y, w, h) every frame, and transform the vertex positions in the vertex shader (`vertex.xy *= guiRect.zw; vertex.xy += guiRect.xy;`).

I know that method #2 *works*, but I want to know which one is *better*.

Comment: If you go with method 2 you can re-use the same geometry for *all* elements.

Comment: Which is precisely why I came up with method 2 in the first place.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. I mistook 'single vertex array object' to mean single-per-GuiElement-instance. Oops :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do like the idea of option two, however, it would be quite inefficient because it requires a draw call for each element. As was mentioned by other replies, the biggest performance gains lie in batching geometry and reducing the number of draw calls. (In other words, reducing the time your application spends communicating with the GL driver).

So I think the fastest possible way of drawing 2D objects with OpenGL is by using a technique similar to your option one, but adding batching to it.

The smallest possible vertex format you need in order to draw a quadrilateral on the screen is a simple `vec2`, with 4 `vec2`s per quadrilateral. The texture coordinates can be generated in a very lightweight vertex shader, such as this:

```
// xy = vertex position in normalized device coordinates ([-1,+1] range).
attribute vec2 vertexPositionNDC;

varying vec2 vTexCoords;

const vec2 scale = vec2(0.5, 0.5);

void main()
{
    vTexCoords  = vertexPositionNDC * scale + scale; // scale vertex attribute to [0,1] range
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPositionNDC, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

In the application side, you can set up a double buffer to optimize throughput, by using two vertex buffers, so you can write to one of them on a given frame then flip the buffers and send it to GL, while you start writing to the next buffer right away:

```
// Update:
GLuint vbo = vbos[currentVBO];
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataOffset, dataSize, data);

// Draw:
glDrawElements(...);

// Flip the buffers:
currentVBO = (currentVBO + 1) % NUM_BUFFERS;
```

Or another simpler option is to use a single buffer, but allocate new storage on every submission, to avoid blocking, like so:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, data, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

This is a well known and used technique for simple async data transfers. [Read this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) for more.

It is also a good idea to use indexed geometry. Keep an index buffer of unsigned shorts with the vertex buffer. A 2-byte per element IB will reduce data traffic quite a bit and should have an index range big enough for any amount of 2D/UI elements that you might wish to draw.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really like the idea.  It might not work for *everything* gui-related (fonts and icons will need special consideration), but this is an excellent approach for the majority of gui work.  I might have to adjust the texture co-ordinates in a smarter manner, especially for borders, but this should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

For GUI elements you could use dynamic vertex buffer (ring buffer) and just upload the geometry every frame because this is quite small amount of geometry data. Then you can batch your GUI element rendering unlike in both of your proposed methods.

Batching is quite important if you render large number of GUI elements, such as text. You can quite easily build a generic GUI rendering system with this which caches the GUI element draw calls and flushes the draws to the GPU upon state changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it like DXUT does it, where it takes the rects from each element, and renders them with a single universal method that takes an element as a parameter, which contains a rect.  Each control can have many elements. It adds the four points of the rect to a buffer in a specific order in `STREAM_DRAW` mode and a constant index buffer.  This does draw each rect individually, but performance is not completely vital, because your geometry is simple, and when you are in a dialog, you can usually put the rendering of the 3d scene on the back burner. EDIT: even using this to do HUD items, it has a negligible performance penalty.

This is a simple and organized way to do it, where it works well with textures, and there are only two shaders, one for drawing textured components, and one for non-textured.  THen there is a special way to do text.

If you want to see how I did it, you can look at this:
https://github.com/kevinmackenzie/ObjGLUF

It is in GLUFGui.h/.cpp

Comment: Sounds like a really complication solution that basically just does what I described with option #2...